# Can I update a column based on COUNT? (SQL)

Tags: sql-server, count

I have 101k records but some of these are duplicates. So when I do a COUNT function I get 50,369 records. Is there a way to put the COUNT in a column so I can see the occurrence number for each record?

Comment: Do a `GROUP BY` on enough columns to identify duplicate rows

Comment: Which database are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle) ?

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, at least to me. Could you share some sample data (just couple of rows, no need for the entire 101K :-)) and the result you're trying to get for it?

Comment: I am using SQL Server

Comment: LatLong          (No column name)
29.93433,-95.74763 666
29.853215,-95.831456 785
29.958664,-95.462685 836

I would like to get the COUNT amount in a column for each time those coordinates are displayed

Comment: Are you wanting to add a column to your database or just include a column in your query? If you are using a type of SQL that has Window Functions (ie, not <MySQL 5.x) then you can use a `COUNT OVER` with a `PARTITION` to get that number.

Comment: @JessicaR Then add `SQL Server` tag to your question.  `SQL` is just a language.

Comment: @Eric will do, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your database supports analytic functions, then `COUNT` can do what you want:

```
SELECT *,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3) dup_cnt
FROM yourTable;
```

This assumes that your table has three columns which constitute whether or not a record is duplicate.  You may adjust this logic accordingly.